# My iPhone keeps telling me my Apple ID cannot be used in the U.S. store and that I need to switch to the Albania store

Tags: iphone, itunes, apple-id

I’m not sure why but my phone keeps thinking I’m from Albania. I ordered the iPhone 7 off of Amazon. I got the phone yesterday and when I finished setting up my Apple ID, I tried to download an app. It immediately said my ID was not in use at the U.S. store and that I needed to review the account, it also said my Apple ID was not in use in the iTunes Store but my iTunes isn’t working. So I went back to my account and it took me to a page where I had to agree to Terms and Service. Above it was a location and it said I was from Albania. I changed it to United States and refilled all my information, then I tried to download an app and it said the same thing. I went to settings and changed my location on there, but it’s not helping to reset the App Store and iTunes. Not sure what I’m doing wrong. I’ve contacted Apple Support and I stayed up until midnight trying to figure it out. We factory reset it so many times and we tried turning my phone off and on again. I’ve tried going to the Apple ID website and changing my location from there but it keeps resetting to Albania as well. I have no idea what’s wrong with it.

Comment: Try contacting Apple Support. Why they are seeing you as in Albania (unless that’s the country you selected during setup *initial* setup)  is only something they would know. If you’re in the US but they are *seeing* you in Albania is something they have to answer.

Comment: If you are not sure how you setup the phone, do a hard reset and start over

Answer (score 2):

There are two possibilities. One common and the other rare.

The common item is your AppleID is steering this. You can solve that with Apple Support directly and I would leave your device out of the picture - just use a computer to go to https://appleid.apple.com and choose your region / locale / banking so that your preferred location pops up when you browse https://www.apple.com and https://support.apple.com

The less common item is that Apple tracks the geography in to which an iPhone is sold. This can not be changed unless you have documented proof as the original purchaser that Apple made a mistake. If a reseller makes a mistake, it’s generally up to them to fix the registration.

This affects things like GPS being disabled, functions like EKG / health / watch being enabled only in regions where it’s officially approved (legally and contractually) by regulatory  agencies (the FDA in the US for example).

Once the AppleID is set, I would erase all content and settings on the iPhone and perform a setup again, and then engage Apple Support if you are not being offered your preferred region. Sometimes a reseller uses an iPhone to set up a bunch of accounts and then sells it, so you might need to talk to your seller if for some reason your phone isn’t working as Apple designed it out of the box.

Ask a pointed question to your buyer - which region did Apple sell this iPhone if you can’t solve this yourself. Tracing back to the contact to which Apple shipped the device (you or a reseller) will make it easy to know if a mistake was made.

Comment: I went on the computer to change it on https://appleid.apple.com , but it said there was an error changing it everytime I tried.